# I'm using vault for secret management with Kubernetes and want all my secrets to be in pod env. i am using this deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm able to inject my secrets to a perticular path `/vault/secret`, but unable to store them as pod env, there is no secret in pod env. Files in pod on path `/vault/secrets` are existing. After that I got 2 questions.

Why its not working and is there any way how can I inject it in pod env's?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: vault-agent-demo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vault-agent-demo
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations: 
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: "update"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-sendmail: "secret/sendmail-api"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-sendmail: |
          {{- with secret "secret/sendmail-api" -}}
          export APIKEY="{{ .Data.data.APIKEY }}"
          {{- end }}
        
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: "update"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret--config: "secret/payment-api"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template--config: |
          {{ with secret "secret/payment-api" -}}
          APIKEY="{{ .Data.data.APIKEY }}""
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "myapp"
      labels:
        app: vault-agent-demo
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: app
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: jweissig/app:0.0.1
        command:
            ['sh', '-c']
        args:
            ['source /vault/secrets/ && /app/web']
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a **Secret** in an **environment variable** in a Pod, please follow the below steps:

For each container in your Pod specification, add an environment variable for the secret key to the below field.

```
env[].valueFrom.secretKeyRef
```

Modify the image or command line so that the program looks for values in the specified environment variables.

For more details, please see the [official](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data) and also check a [document](https://faun.pub/using-kubernetes-secrets-as-environment-variables-5ea3ef7581ef#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20Pod,used%20to%20create%20the%20pod.) written by Madeesha.

Comment: @Abhinav Dadhich is your issue resolved? let me know if you need any additional help.